# Rotation with AutoLayout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, autolayout

I'm beginner in Xcode and I'm using ios6 with autolayout.

I would like to rotate my uiviewcontroller from:

[image]

to:

[image]

I would like to prevent my bottom bar from rotating.  Something very similar to Apple's camera app rotation, but whats going wrong is that everything rotates.

I tried to put some code like

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{   
    // [Bar setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -2.0)];
    // [Bar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
}
```

Comment: Check out these autolayout tutorials by raywenderlich may help you to get it work. [Beginning Auto Layout in iOS 6: Part 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) [Beginning Auto Layout in iOS 6: Part 2/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2)

Comment: Thank you but i already check this and also wwdc 2012 videos for auto layout and rotation with iOS6, but i can't find out how to set some uiview fixed during rotation !

Comment: @Robert, We have same problem in rotation view I want to add 10 button in single view (3 in one row) UI for portrait,Landscape it is perfect in Portrait, please provide some help to manage ui by autolayout and IB in ios7] –

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to achieve it by IB, but you can do that by adding specific constraints through code:

```c
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
    [self.view removeConstraints:landscapeConstraints];
  } else {
    [self.view addConstraints:landscapeConstraints];
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, are you sure your view is actually rotating?

If so, what you're going to want to do is fix the bottom of the green view to the bottom of its superview. You should be able to do this in Interface Builder. Select your green view, and click the Constraints button at the bottom of your Storyboard file (the middle one):
[image: add constraints button]

Next, select "Bottom Space to Superview" as seen in the image below:
[image: pin bottom space to superview]

This will set a constraint saying "always keep the bottom of this view pinned to the bottom of its superview". Doing so should get you the result you're looking for. I set it up in a quick sample project. Here is what the views look like in Portrait and Landscape, respectively:

[image: portrait]
[image: landscape]

Comment: OP _wants_ the bottom bar to move to the side on rotation.

Comment: Well, the screenshots contradict what he asks. "I would like to prevent my bottom bar from rotating"

Comment: He says he wants to prevent it from rotating, which means not move.

Comment: This is exactly against what the OP says they want, and does not match their desired screenshots.

Comment: "I would like to prevent my bottom bar from rotating. Something very similar to Apple's camera app rotation, but whats going wrong is that everything rotates." The screenshots are what IS happening, not what he wants.

Comment: @jmstone, We have same problem in rotation view I want to add 10 button in single view (3 in one row) UI for portrait,Landscape it is perfect in Portrait, please provide some help to manage ui by autolayout in ios7]

Comment: @DineshPatel I would recommend posting a new SO question and providing the code/constraints/ etc you have already tried.